# html php Form not working (data is not ending up in database)

Tags: php, html, mysql, database, forms

hi i have a problem delivering data to the database using a html/Php form ,
so this is suppose to be a website were people already register with (email , password, and full name .then this form is optionally used to add (address ,city,country etc.)but its not work .

```
<?php 
 session_start();
 require 'db.php';    //here is all the database connection settings //
?>
<?php 
 if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {   
  if (isset($_POST['addinfo'])) { //user logging in
     require 'addinfo.php';      
    }
  }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
        <div class="container2">
        <form class="modal-content animate" method="post" 
   action="account.php" style="z-index:10">
    <input type="text" placeholder='Country' name='country'id="q2"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder='City' name='city'id="q3"/>
    <input type="text" placeholder='Address' name='address'id="q4"/>  
    <input type="text" placeholder='PostalCode' 
   name='postalcode'id="q5"/>    
    <button type="submit" id="sbmt" name='addinfo'>Submit</button>
    <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; float:right; margin- 
   right:34px;">change password</a>         
            </form>
        </div>  
  </body>
```

this is the document addinfo.php

```
 <?php
 require 'db.php';$_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
 $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
 $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
 $_SESSION['postalcode'] = $_POST['postalcode'];

 $country = $_POST['country'];
 $city = $_POST['city'];
 $postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
 $address = $_POST['address'];


 $sql = "INSERT INTO users (country, city, postalcode, address) " 
  . "VALUES ('$country','$city','$postalcode','$address')";

 ?>
```

this is db.php

```
 <?php
 $servidor = "localhost";
 $usuario= "root";
 $password = "";
 $base_datos = "accounts";

 $host = 'localhost';
 $user = 'root';
 $pass = '';
 $db = 'users';
 $mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user,$pass,$db) or die($mysqli->error);




 $conexion = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $base_datos);
 $conexion1 = new mysqli($servidor, $usuario, $password, $base_datos);


  ?>
```

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized **prepared statements** instead of manually building your queries. They are provided by [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) or by [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Never trust any kind of input, especially that which comes from the client side. Even when your queries are executed only by trusted users, [you are still in risk of corrupting your data](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: `require 'db.php'` is called twice, do you have error checking on?

Comment: Your form is pointing to account.php, but the name of your php script is addinfo.php

Comment: @MichaelvE `addinfo.php` is required inside the if post condition

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you shoul use mysqli_real_escape_string before inserting data into your database for security. [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/tr/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
$country = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['country']);
$city = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['city']);
$postalcode = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['postalcode']);
$address = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['address']);
```

> The problem in your code: You didn't executing the query.

Add this below the $sql

```
$mysqli->query($sql);
//OR
//mysqli_query($mysqli, $sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a much problem. I liked that you asked this question so you missed a line after your SQL query.

This is the code given below in your document `addinfo.php`.

```
<?php
require 'db.php';
if(isset($_POST['addinfo'])) {
    $_SESSION['country'] = $_POST['country'];
    $_SESSION['city'] = $_POST['city'];
    $_SESSION['address'] = $_POST['address'];
    $_SESSION['postalcode'] = $_POST['postalcode'];

    $country = $_POST['country'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $postalcode = $_POST['postalcode'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];


    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (country, city, postalcode, address) " . "VALUES ('$country','$city','$postalcode','$address')";
    $mysqli->query($sql);

?>
```

I hope this answer will solve your problem.